# Magento custom shipping cost

Tags: magento

Is there a way to add a custom shipping rate for to basket (order) in magento not from admin but in programing.

What I need is, I will have a field with each product "shipping_cost" , now suppose customer added 3 products to basket, now the shipping cost of the order will be the highest of shipping_costs of the products. For example, the 3 products have shipping_costs like $10, $20 and $30 , so the shipping_cost for basket will be $30.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your condition you need to get maximum shipping rate and assign that value to `$shippingprice`. You can add your custom shipping price for an order in magento using given code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($incrementId, 'increment_id');
    
$shippingprice = 30;
    
$order->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
    
$order->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice); 
$order->setGrandTotal($order->getGrandTotal() + $shippingprice); //adding shipping price to grand total
    
$order->save();
```

It will update your shipping price and grand total. I guess it will be helpful to you.